# Problems trying to install VUE\CLI using the latest version of NPM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, installation, command-line-interface

I am trying to install VUE/CLI, but I am getting multiple errors during the install. I used Visual Studio Code command line terminal, and Node\npm with the command line screen, and I still getting the same results.

1. I got the latest version of NodeJS (v16.13.1) and NPM (8.3.0).
2. Run npm install -g @vue/cli
3. got the error npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
4. Reading similar post, I ran npm cache ckear --force
5. Run npm install -g @vue/cli again.
6. The install process hangs while in this process: reify:rxjs: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs/-/rxjs-6.6.7.tgz 16557ms (cache miss)
7. Got error: 6455 error code ECONNRESET
   6456 error syscall read

   ```
           6457 error errno -4077

           6458 error network read ECONNRESET

           6459 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

           6459 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
           settings.

           6459 error network

           6459 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

           6459 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

           6460 verbose exit -4077
   ```
8. I tried using npm config rm proxy and npm config rm https- proxy and had no luck.
9. I retried again following the steps above and got
   npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
   npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
   npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/es-abstract/-/es-abstract-1.19.1.tgz

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change your DNS to google like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BD264pKWzc